# Method to return a DateTime-List of non booked appointments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a site for customers to book appointments. So I'm trying to return a list of free bookable appointments, and the goal is, that you don't gonna be able to book a time if it is already been booked.

My first method (public List AllTimes) returns a list of ALL the bookabe appointment-times for a choosen day, even the ones that are alredy booked. So it returns a list so you can pick a time every 15 minutes i a table. Every table-cell starts off depending of witch type of appiontment you have choosen(int behandlingslangd). So the returned list can look something like this if the choosen appointment-lenght for example is 60minutes:

8.00 - 9.00

8.15 - 9.15

8.30 - 9.30

8.45 - 9.45

9.00 -10.00

9.15 - 10.15

9.30 -10.30

9.45 - 10.45

So far, everything is fine!
But with my second method (public List NonBookedTimes) I'm trying to return a list of just free appointments. You don't gonna be able to book an appointment that's alredy been booked. And my if-statement in my second method almost achieve what I'm trying to do. For example: if an appointment already been booked 9.15, that time in my table has been removed. But the 2 times just before, and the time just after witch is overlapping is still there in my table, so I can't figure out what else to add to my if-statment to fix that.
So my goal is that I want my table to look like this (if the choosen time is 60min):

8.00 - 9.00

8.15 - 9.15

10.15 -11.15

10.30 - 11.30

```
 public List<DateTime> AllTimes(int behandlingsLangd, List<Bokningstider> oppetTider, DateTime datum)
    {
        List<DateTime> _myList = new List<DateTime>();

        foreach (var item in oppetTider)
        {
            var startTid = new DateTime(datum.Year, datum.Month, datum.Day, item.StartTidTimme, item.StartTidMinut, 00);
            var SlutTid = new DateTime(datum.Year, datum.Month,datum.Day, item.SlutTidTimme, item.SlutTidMinut, 00);
            for (DateTime i = startTid; i.AddMinutes(behandlingsLangd) <= SlutTid; i = i.AddMinutes(15))
            {
                _myList.Add(i);
            }
        }
        return _myList;
    }


public List<DateTime> NonBookedTimes(List<DateTime> AllTimes, DateTime datum, int? behandlingsId)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var query = from a in _db.AppointmentDiary
                    where a.DateTimeScheduled.Year == datum.Year
                    && a.DateTimeScheduled.Month == datum.Month
                    && a.DateTimeScheduled.Day == datum.Day
                    select a.DateTimeScheduled;

        var bokningsTider = _db.BokningsTider;

        AppointmentDiary rec = new AppointmentDiary();
        List<DateTime> tider = new List<DateTime>();

        foreach (var Tid in AllTimes)
        {
            tider.Add(Tid);
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                if (item <= Tid) // ---------- Here I think I need to extend my if-statment
                {
                    tider.Remove(Tid);              
                }
            }

        }
        return tider;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm just thinking here but you could do the check like this.

```
List<Datetime> ledige_Timer =  AllTimes.Where(a=> !query.Contain(a)).toList();
```

You select all times that don't exist in query.

There is a lot different i would have done with the structure and planning of the code. but as a quick fix i think this would work.

What i would do is to create a appointment class and then have a list of appointment classes.

Keep in mind this is just a suggestion, to ease the load of future work. the class could be the DB table containing a bool, a userID, start-time and timespan it would work the same way.

```
class planner{
    List<Appointment> Appointments = new List<Appointment>();
    void initDay(){
    Datetime baseTime = new Datetime(8,0,0);//8 o'clock

        for(int a = 0; a<8; a++){
            Appointments.Add(new Appointment(new Datetime(H,M,0),new Timespan(1,0,0))); 
            baseTime.Add(new timespan(0,15,0)); //Add 15 minutes
        }

        //Now you have a list of appointents where you can ask for all openings 
        //of all appointments by simply asking

        var UnFilled = Appointments.Where(a=>!a.isFilled());
        var Filled = Appointments.Where(a=>a.isFilled());
    }
}
public class Appointment{

    User filled = null;
    Datetime start;
    Timespan time;// Makes for adjustable time span

    public Appointment(Datetime Start, Timespan Time){
         start = Start;
         time = Time;
    }
    public void fillAppointment(User Fill){
        filled = Fill;
    }
    public bool isFilled(){
        return filled != null? true:false;
    }
}
```